# Pyspark, executors lost connectivity when performing a join

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, mesos

My mesos-spark cluster:

[image]

Executors are crashing every time I try to do a .count() after a join, the count without the join works perfectly, not sure why but in failed queries I see:

[image]

And in the executor logs:

[image]

I don't see an specific OOM issue, what's the deal here? It seems to happen only when the join is made.

Followed @busfighter suggestions and set the dataframes to StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY before joining and reduced partitions using coalesce().
Still the same error.

**Edit 1**

Tried all comments, nothing:

1. Saving to memory the data
2. Repartitioned to 12 partition (was 200), to be added that after checking the spark/jobs web UI the executors are never specifically removed by Spark(Mesos) on my cluster
3. Changed value spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold to 20 smaller the default value

**Edit 2**

At no given point, when the task fails the executors are removed, they just timeout on shuffle:

[image]

**Edit 3**

See that the data size is really small when it crashes, feeling lost and can't find the executor logs to see if it was killed becaues of OOM:

[image]

**Edit 4**

Some important notes:

- The job works OK with only 1 slave (takes more time) but it doesnt crash, I don't think its an OOM issue.
- Other parts of the code, that don't involve joining data (merely reading and transforming work OK)

Config used on PySpark

```
conf = (SparkConf()
        .setAppName('daily_etl')
        .setMaster(XXXXX)
        .set("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1")
        .set('spark.mesos.executor.home','/opt/spark')
        )

spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config(conf=conf) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

**Edit 5**

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

**Edit 6**

Adding screenshot of the Mesos UI

[image]

**Edit 7**

Managed to narrow down the problem, for some reason BlockManager is listening to localhost, hence the other executors cannot conect:

[image]

Not sure why but will crate another topic.

Comment: I guess the problem is in your storagelevel and partitioning. When you do the join it starts shuffling and if storage level is not memory_only it tries to read the partition which don't fit in the memory. You can try to set storage level to MEMORY_ONLY and repartition your frame to more smaller partitions.

Comment: @busfighter thanks the reply! Is there not any way to find this in the logs? I am quite shocked that with so many small data this happens(less than 1giga data with 20 gigas in the cluster)

Comment: check this `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html

Comment: Can you add your code ?

Comment: @JohnDoe It's basically reading two mongo dbs, and doing a join... The task runs perfectly (and within seconds) when using a single slave, but with more, it crashes, any idea?

Comment: Can you post your Spark submit statement.

Comment: @JohnDoe Posted the configuration I use for my submit, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
conf = (SparkConf()
        .setAppName('daily_etl')
        .setMaster(XXXXX)
        .set("spark.jars.packages", "org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.4.1")
        .set("spark.mesos.executor.home","/opt/spark")
        .set("spark.driver.memory", "16G")
        .set("spark.executor.memory","8G")
        .set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", "-1")
        )
```

Maybe also do a repartition

```
df = df.repartition(2000)
```

Value depends on cluster

Comment: Hi, that didn't work.
My executors have each 4G Ram, I can't set so much, and my driver 1. I don't think it's a capacity problem as it works with one single slave.
Also there was a small syntax error in the last "set", there are " missing for the key and value.

Thanks for your help anyways but the problem perists.

Comment: It seems that there is a connection problem with your executor (s) `failed to connect to..`. Can you test with another script whether it is actually executed on the executor (s)? Do you have access to the Mesos-UI to monitor your cluster?

Comment: thanks for all your help! I was thinking of running a very simple pypspark script that forces a cooperation between my slaves but I am not sure how to do it! And yes I have a Mesos UI, all the slaves are connected correctly to the master(they show on the slaves tab), but the issue I think is talking beteween them, see last screenshot!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mesos (using Yarn) but check this: https://hub.packtpub.com/how-to-run-spark-in-mesos/ **Cluster mode**